# ¿Cómo limitar el tamaño de un gráfico?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un codigo que traza un graph pero me gustaría que se limitará al eje de la abscisa, el tiempo :

```
# Set up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Plot the actual values
ax.plot(train['ds'], train['y'], 'ko-', linewidth = 1.4, alpha = 0.8, ms = 1.8, label = 'Observations')
ax.plot(test['ds'], test['y'], 'ko-', linewidth = 1.4, alpha = 0.8, ms = 1.8, label = 'Observations')

# Plot the predicted values
ax.plot(future['ds'], future['yhat'], 'navy', linewidth = 2.4, label = 'Predicted');

# Plot the uncertainty interval as ribbon
ax.fill_between(future['ds'].dt.to_pydatetime(), future['yhat_upper'], future['yhat_lower'], alpha = 0.6,
               facecolor = 'gold', edgecolor = 'k', linewidth = 1.4, label = 'Confidence Interval')

# Put a vertical line at the start of predictions
plt.vlines(x=min(test['ds']).date(), ymin=min(future['yhat_lower']), ymax=max(future['yhat_upper']), colors = 'r',
           linestyles='dashed', label = 'Prediction Start')

# Plot formatting
plt.legend(loc = 2, prop={'size': 8}); plt.xlabel('Date'); plt.ylabel('Price $');
plt.grid(linewidth=0.6, alpha = 0.6)

plt.title('{} Model Evaluation from {} to {}.'.format(self.symbol,
    start_date.date(), end_date.date()));
plt.show();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que se limitará al eje de la abscisa, el tiempo. Me gustaría decirle cuándo parar.

Creo que tiene algo que ver con :

```
        ax.fill_between(future['ds'].dt.to_pydatetime(), future['yhat_upper'], future['yhat_lower'], alpha = 0.6,
```

Pero no he logrado cambiarlo, por ejemplo para poner algo entre paréntesis.

Comment: Más fácil que limitar el eje al pintar el plot puede ser usar `pandas` para seleccionar el rango de fechas deseado y pasarle a `.plot()` el dataframe "recortado". Es más sencillo si usas la fecha como `index` mediante un `train = train.set_index("ds")`, etc.

Comment: También puedes usar `ax.set_xlim()` pasándole objetos de tipo `datetime`, como puedes ver en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21424306/1264820)